# Meet "dyld: Library not loaded of wrong architecture" for libquadmath.0.dylib when running scip

Tags: scip

I installed SCIP Optimization Suite from the [SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2-Darwin-Ipopt-gcc10.sh](https://scipopt.org/#download) installer of precompiled binary.
I also installed gcc and tbb by running:

```
brew install gcc
brew install tbb
```

Error message:

```
$ SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2-Darwin/bin/scip
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/7/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/it/VirtualBox/10运筹学/14SCIP/01install/SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2-Darwin/bin/scip
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/7/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/local/lib/7/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
    /usr/local/lib/7/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
[1]    93720 abort      SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2-Darwin/bin/scip
```

There is other libquadmath.0.dylib with x86_64 architecture installed:

```
$ sudo find / -name libquadmath.0.dylib
Password:
/usr/local/lib/7/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/7/libquadmath.0.dylib
/usr/local/opt/lib/gcc/7/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib
/usr/local/opt/lib/gcc/7/libquadmath.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/4.6.4/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.6.4/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/4.6.4/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.6.4/libquadmath.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.6/4.6.4/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.6.4/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.6/4.6.4/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.6.4/libquadmath.0.dylib
/Users/it/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
/Users/it/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib
/Users/it/miniconda3/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/.dylibs/libquadmath.0.dylib

$ lipo /usr/local/lib/7/libquadmath.0.dylib -archs
x86_64
```

I wonder why scip did not find these dylibs with right architecture?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Why does scip find this lib under /usr/local/lib/7/i386/ but not /usr/local/lib/7/?

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure you have the correct version of gcc installed, the installer that you downloaded asks for version 10.

Second, try installing all prerequisites first and then rerunning the installer-script afterwards.

If that does not help, please check the output of `otool -L SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2-Darwin/bin/scip` and `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to see if the library in question is loaded.

Lastly, you can try to patch the binary by adjusting the path to the library for the correct one:

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/lib/7/i386/libquadmath.0.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib SCIPOptSuite-7.0.2-Darwin/bin/scip
```